# Why no memory leak for: @property(copy) NSString* name, when I don't release it in dealloc?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, ios8

**I turned ARC off.**

I have a property in a class declared like this:

```
@property(copy) NSString* name
```

I set `name` with a constant string:

```
[greeter setName:@"Jane"];
```

I implemented `dealloc` for my class like this:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I expected there would be a memory leak because I didn't release `name`.  I'm using Xcode 6.2 and `Product>Analyze` does not identify any leaks, and neither does Instruments: `Product>Profile, choose Leaks, hit the red Record button`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
//
//  Greeter.h
//  Flashlight2
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Greeter : NSObject

@property(copy) NSString* name; 

-(NSString*)description;
-(void)dealloc;


@end
```

....

```
//
//  Greeter.m
//  Flashlight2
//

#import "Greeter.h"

@implementation Greeter


-(NSString*)description {
    NSString* msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"I am a Greeter"];
    return [msg autorelease];
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

...

```
@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Greeter* greeter = [[Greeter alloc] init];
    [greeter setName:@"Jane"];  //constant string in memory for life of program

    NSLog(@"%@", greeter);
    [greeter release];


    return YES;
}
```

After thinking about it for awhile, the only explanation that I can come up with is that the `name setter` doesn't *actually* copy the constant string. It seems like  Obj-C does a type check on `the string being assigned` to the property, and because it's a constant string, Obj-C just assigns(?) `the-pointer-to-the-constant-string` to the `name-pointer`. Is something like that going on?

Comment: This is not related to your question but with a tag of ios8 I am assuming you are not dealing with pre-ARC legacy code so I am curious as to why you would want to turn ARC off?

Comment: @Rog, To learn about memory management.

Comment: Yup, that's the only good reason I could think of :)

Comment: Feel free to explore the `NSString` memory management idiosyncrasies, but be wary of generalizing any of your conclusions, as `NSString` is highly optimized and behaves quite atypically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's two optimizations at work here that combine to cause this result.

First: NSString literals are stored in a special segment of the binary, rather than allocated at runtime. They ignore retain and release, and are never allocated or deallocated.

Second: Copying an immutable NSString (including a string literal) instead just retains it, because the copy would be guaranteed to always be identical to the original. (This is accomplished by overriding the -copyWithZone: method in the private NSString subclass)

So in your scenario, the copy turns into a retain, the retain is ignored, and the deallocation wouldn't happen even if you did properly release the string in dealloc.